# Win7 sysprep /generalize causes failure: "Windows could not complete the installation"

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

Been trying to get myself some experience doing deployments on some old hard drives I have laying around. I install Windows 7 x64 on a reference machine, and log in with audit mode (Ctrl+Shift+F3 at windows welcome instead of putting in user settings) along with the following drivers:

- nVidia GeForce
- Realtek LAN
- Realtek audio
- Intel chipset

In addition, I install Chrome and any Windows updates that are required (SP1).

When I'm ready to image, I use sysprep with the generalize and oobe option.

However, when I reboot windows hangs at the "Setup is starting services" with the message: "Windows could not complete the installation. To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation."

At this point, my keyboard doesn't work. No lights nor input. Mouse doesn't work either. I cannot do Shift+F10 to get to the command prompt.

From here, I simply hard-reset the machine. It brings up the Windows alternative startup, and I choose Safe Mode. However, Setup still gives the error that it cannot continue in safemode, but that's okay because I can at least Shift+F10 to get to a command prompt. From here, I can enable the Admin account, reboot, and setup goes along happily.

Now, if I don't use /generalize, everything goes smoothly.

Why is it that I have to enable the Admin account for the procedure to continue? And why does the whole thing hang when it boots normally, requiring me to go into safe mode? I've read that this may be due to drivers / registry issues, but I have no idea why enabling the Admin account would make it work all of a sudden.

Any insight?

Comment: Have you tried the same steps with Win 7 32bit?  I ran into the same problem with Win 7 64 bit.  My way around this was, to create a flashdrive with Windows PE on it and then just use ImageX to create a image from the PC as it is.

Comment: I have not tried Win7 x86 as that is not that target. Even with WinPE, I still need to perform sysprep /generalize in order to deploy the image to other computers, and it's the sysprep that seems to be failing

Comment: Are you working with WDS? I have a nice website that can help you over here http://richardsower.blogspot.com/2012/04/sysprep-and-capture-windows-image-using.html